# How to clip any image according to Shapefile using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, gis, raster, shapefile, geopandas

I have plotted an image and a shapefile in the same axis of a figure. I want to clip the image according to the outer boundary of the shapefile, I don't know how to. Can anybody help?

[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Itjr.png) and here's a code sample:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))

ax.imshow(arr,extent=[88.2921,88.410967,22.452616,22.6309594])

kolkata.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='red')
```

Comment: the library "rasterio" is the answer

Answer (score 0):

it would be very advantageous to use QGIS UI for such basic operations. It is also possible to write Python scripts with pyQGIS. It may also be useful to examine the GDAL library.

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/90999) is an answer to a similar question.

[And this one](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/02/clip-raster-using-shapefile.html) can also help.